# Getting a control's parent form - vba vb6

Tags: winforms, vba, winapi, vb6

in vba \ vb6 I'm looking for a function that receives a control and returns a  reference to the form on which its placed.

Control.Container isn't my first priority because it may be a frame or a picturebox, and then it'll force me to iterate through all possible containers until i get to the form of it.

any easier way ?

Comment: a "while typeof parent" style loop is the only way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Control.Parent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa268065(v=VS.60).aspx) should get you what you need.

Comment: I didn't think that Parent worked differently from Container in this case, Eric.  So, I tested it and you are correct, as I'm sure you already knew.  Thanks for the pointer!