# How to get parent form of nested VB6 UserControl

Tags: vb6

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31874510/getting-a-controls-parent-form-vba-vb6), which unfortunately does not help me.  When I make a call to `UserControl.Parent`, either a `Form` or another `UserControl` can be returned.  If a Form is returned, I have what I want.  But if a `UserControl` is returned, I have no way of iterating up the chain, since `UserControl` is the base class name, and I do not have access to the base class name outside of the control's implementation.

Technically, I could probably get around this by exposing the Parent property on every single `UserControl` in the application, but I would really like to avoid doing this (we have thousands of them).

My ultimate goal is to get a reference to the parent form which is hosting the control, so that the control can subscribe to the `Form_Unload` event.  Here the control will remove and clean up a hosted .NET interopped control which is preventing the VB6 `UserControl` from raising its `UserControl_Terminated` event, thus leaking GDI objects and memory.

So far I have tried to make calls to `GetParent()`, `GetWindow()` and `GetAncestor()` functions in USER32.dll in the `UserControl_Initialize` and `UserControl_Resize` events, and then cross referencing with the hWnds on the forms in the `Forms` collection, but both of these events seem to be raised before the UserControl has been sited on its host form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find the parent form by traversing parent/child relationships using HWNDs and the win32 API.  My code is roughly as follows:

```
Private Declare Function GetParent Lib "USER32" (ByVal Hwnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetClassName Lib "USER32" Alias "GetClassNameA" _
    (ByVal Hwnd As Long, ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal nMaxCount As Long) As Long

Public Function FindParentForm(Hwnd As Long) As Form
    Dim ParentHwnd As Long
    Dim CandidateForm As Form
    Dim strTmp As String * 255
    Dim lngLngth As Long
    Dim strTitle As String
    ParentHwnd = Hwnd

    Do While (Not ParentHwnd = 0)
        ParentHwnd = GetParent(ParentHwnd)
        lngLngth = GetClassName(ParentHwnd, strTmp, 255)
        strTitle = Left(strTmp, lngLngth)
        'ThunderFormDC is the Debug version of a VB6 form, and ThunderRT6FormDC is the Release/Runtime version of a VB6 form
        If strTitle = "ThunderFormDC" Or strTitle = "ThunderRT6FormDC" Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop

    For Each CandidateForm In Forms
        If CandidateForm.Hwnd = ParentHwnd Then
            Set FindParentForm2 = CandidateForm
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    'Didn't find the parent form somehow
    Set FindParentForm2 = Nothing
End Function
```

As I mentioned in the question, the problem with this solution is that during the UserControl_Initialize and UserControl_Resize events, the parent/child relationships have not been setup between HWNDs yet.  If you try to traverse the parent/child relationships, you will find that the parent of the usercontrol is a class named "Static".

I was able to work around this issue by searching for the parent form in a manual `Init()` procedure for my user control.  However, many forms do not call the `Init()` procedure unless the tab it is on is clicked on (in an attempt to get some sort of lazy loading implemented in VB6).  I was able to work around this by refactoring the control to not dynamically create/add the .NET interopped control until the `Init()` procedure was called.  By this time, the parent/child relationships seem to be set up.

An alternative solution to the lazy loading problem is to hook a `WndProc` procedure, and listen for the `WM_CHILDACTIVATED` message.  However, this message only gets sent when the child control changes parents.  It does not propogate to grandchildren.  It should, however, be possible to hook another `WndProc` to the new parent control and listen for it's own `WM_CHILDACTIVATED` message and so on until a child control gets parented to a `ThunderForm`.  However, since `WndProc` can only be implemented in a static module, I didn't feel like keeping track of parent/child relationships.

Answer (score 2):

I did some fiddling around, and this should give you something to go on. I just created two UserControls, called Internal and External.  Internal has a command button, External has a frame.  I put an instance of Internal on External, inside the frame.  Then I put an instance of External on a form, whose name I just left at Form1.

So, I have a control within a control on a form.  The problem is to find a reference to Form from the context of the internal control.

First, I have a method called Test on the Form, so:

```
Public Sub Test
    MsgBox "Test Succeeded"
End Sub
```

Now, in the internal control's command button's Click event handler:

```
Private Sub cmdTest_Click()
    UserControl.ParentControls(0).Parent.Test
End Sub
```

Running the Form project and clicking the command button successfully calls the Form's Test method. (Yee ha.)

So, to distinguish between a nested control and a control directly on the form, you can do something along these lines:

```
Private Sub cmdTest_Click()
    If TypeOf UserControl.Parent is Form Then
        UserControl.Parent.Test
    Else
        UserControl.ParentControls(0).Parent.Test
    End If
End Sub
```

I then tried nesting the external control in another control (External2) and putting an instance of External2 on the form.  In the debug window, I did this:

```
? typename(usercontrol.ParentControls(0))
External
? typename(usercontrol.ParentControls(0).Parent)
External2
```

And that's as far as I got.  Trying things like this:

```
? typename(usercontrol.ParentControls(0).Parent.ParentControls(0))
```

or anything similar, got an "Object doesn't support this property or method" error.

If you need to evaluate controls nested more than one deep (you haven't said for sure, but "iterate up the chain" suggests that you might), that might be beyond the capabilities of this technique.  You can mess with the Controls and Name properties as well, and maybe figure something out.  But it looks like the ParentControls property doesn't extend to parents of controls that are themselves controls, unless of course you go to the trouble of exposing them with a different property name.  At least you can iterate one more link up the chain with this.

In general, it doesn't look like the Parent property or its derivatives contain actual references to the parent objects, but some sort of subset of their properties and methods.  For example, I can get the hWnd property of the UserControl, but not of UserControl.Parent.  Even specifically referencing the parent by name (the name of the actual control instance is External1, so ? External1.hWnd) fails to get the hWnd property, throwing an "Object Required" error.  That would appear to complicate the possibility of using the API for a solution.

Anyway, I leave it to you to play around with.  If you get further than I have, I would be interested to see your results.

Comment: I can think of at least a couple instances where we need to nest 3 `UserControl`s deep.  I wouldn't be surprised if there are a few instances where we nest deeper.

I was able to have some luck using the win32 api to find the parent form - I'll post that here when I get back to work tomorrow.  It's not a complete solution to my question here, but I was able to refactor my control to make it work.

Comment: That's cool.  Looking forward to seeing your solution, and what is still incomplete about it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm rusty, but isn't the `Container` property what you're after?

Be aware, when interopping with dot net, that dot net has very different garbage collection. Just because the VB6 objects have been released doesn't mean that the dot net objects have been. They could still be lurking in memory and - in rare cases - could still be firing events on timers.

So make sure that your dot net control is cleaning itself up properly, and has a method which VB6 can fire in order to force this termination to occur.

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445702(v=vs.60).aspx

Comment: The `Container` property has two issues.  First, `UserControl`'s do not have a `Container` property.  You must get it off of the `UserControl.Extender` property.  Second, the `Container` may be another `UserControl`.  Since the `UserControl.Extender` property is a base class property, it is not accessible outside of that `UserControl`'s specific implementation.  I.e. `UserControl1` cannot access `UserControl2.UserControl.Extender.Container`.  Thus the `Container` property has the same problems as the `Parent` property - I would need to modify every user control in our application (too many).

Answer (score 0):

I solved my referencing problem using UserControl.Parent in **ReadProperty**.
I tried GetParent() with no success. Also tried UserControl.Parent in **Initialize**.
The problem is that during Initialize the object doesn't exist. It is being builted before link to form (Parent).
In **ReadProperty** (or Resize) it already exists and you will be able to use UserControl.Parent.
For example, I use UserControl.Parent.name to save some information in window register.

Answer (score 0):

This is asociated with this topic so I post it here for use as necessary in special limited cases. It can't get too deep into the nesting, but was is a quick way to get information in my case and others may find it of use.

I have a a Control (cmdPageDown1) placed on a User Control, that is placed on a User Control (xMCGridNew1), which is placed on a Form (frmMC).

As others have pointed out, I can't get to the Form Name with any quick single line of code, BUT with these simple lines, I can get the names of the other 2 nested user controls and the lower level Control.

For Example:

```
        'Debug.Print '[Roadblock Here]         'Top Level  frm MC    (Parent)
        Debug.Print Screen.ActiveControl.Name 'SubLevel 1 xMCGridNew1 (Child)
        Debug.Print UserControl.Name          'SubLevel 2 xpage (GrandChild)
        Debug.Print ActiveControl.Name        'SubLevel 3 cmdPageDown1 (Great Grandchild)
```

This will yield in the immediate window corresponding to the three nest levels.

```
xMCGridNew1
xPage  
cmdPageDown1
```

As mentioned by another poster (Orignal Poster) in this thread, regarding attempted use of the Container property:

> The Container property has two issues. First, UserControl's do not have a >Container property. You must get it off of the UserControl.Extender >property. Second, the Container may be another UserControl. Since the >UserControl.Extender property is a base class property, it is not accessible >outside of that UserControl's specific implementation. I.e. UserControl1 >cannot access UserControl2.UserControl.Extender.Container. Thus the >Container property has the same problems as the Parent property - I would >need to modify every user control in our application (too many). – Taedrin >Jan 15 '16 at 15:08

Answer (score 0):

You could also do another workaround, with parsing from the control level down to the Form level:

```
Public Function FindParentForm(ByVal ctrl As Control) As Form
  Do
    If TypeOf ctrl.Container Is Form Then
      Set FindParentForm = ctrl.Container
      Exit Function
    Else
      Set ctrl = ctrl.Container
    End If
  Loop Until False 'Will never hit as there is always a Form at the lowest level
End Function
```

Or a much simpeler solution as the Parent of a Control is always the Form which it resides on, so even if you have a couple of usercontrols stacked onto each other, the Parent of the highest Usercontrol will still be the Form the lowest Usercontrol is residing on.

```
Public Function ParentForm(ByVal ctrl As Control) As Form
  Set ParentForm = ctrl.Parent
End Function
```

And an example on how to use above:

```
Public Sub Test()
   Debug.Print ParentForm(MyUserControl).Name
   Debug.Print ControlContainer(MyUserControl).Name        
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you considered the [OP's comment about `Container`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34798471/how-to-get-parent-form-of-nested-vb6-usercontrol#comment57369969_34808418)?

Comment: Yes, the UserControl doesn't have the Container property, BUT the Control object does have it, and any UserControl is a Control object. I tested the code myself. (I'll edit my answer with an example so it's clear WHY ctrl is defined as Control).

Comment: The OP is saying that they want to detect the parent form from the inside of a UserControl that itself can be inside another UserControl, in which case Container or Parent do not work.

Comment: as I said, the above code does work on any usercontrol. Have you actually tried it yourself? I have checked the code I listed. The Parent is always the form, no matter on which level you are, so put a frame (or UserControl) on a frame on a frame on a frame, and if you check the parent of the last frame you'll see it still will give you the form as parent. Now if you want to know the container from inside the usercontrol you can always call ControlContainer(MyUserControl).Container or ContraolContainer(MyLabedl).Container as the `Control` object does have the Container property.