# Problems with calling function and sub in modular format

Tags: excel, vba

I am going to integrate few structure-like sub as follows:

```
Private Sub txtToNextLVEXP_Recheck()

    If txtToNextLVEXP.Value Like "ABC" Then
        txtToNextLVEXP.Value = txtToNextLVEXP_Min & " AND " & txtToNextLVEXP_Max
        txtToNextLVEXP_check
    End If

End Sub
```

And

```
Private Sub txtTargetLV_Recheck()

    If txtTargetLV.Value Like "ABC" Then
        txtTargetLV.Value = txtTargetLV_Min & " And " & txtTargetLV_Max
        txtTargetLV_check
    End If

End Sub
```

txtToNextLVEXP_Min, txtToNextLVEXP_Max, txtTargetLV_Min and txtTargetLV_Max are functions;
txtTargetLV and txtTargetLV are MSForms.Control;
txtToNextLVEXP_check and txtTargetLV_check are Sub(s).

It is possible to merge them to be something as follows?

```
Private Sub Recheck(target as MSForms.Control)

    If target.Value Like "ABC" Then
        target.Value = (target & "_Min") & " AND " & (target & "_Max")
        target & "_check"
    End If

End Sub
```

I stuck with the renaming of target_Min, target_max and target_check, please advice, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with something similar to this:

```
Private Sub Recheck(target As MSForms.Control)
Dim strTarget As String
    strTarget = "txtTargetLV"           'or the bellow?
    'strTarget = target.Name

With yourFormName                       'if you are not on userform, you can access controls via userform name, otherwise "Me" will do
    If target.Value Like "ABC" Then
        target.Value = .Controls(strTarget & "_Min").Value & " AND " & .Controls(strTarget & "_Max").Value
        Application.Run (strTarget & "_check")       'If you are trying to call a function based on the name of your control...
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

I`m not 100% sure I understand what you are trying to achieve, but hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much!! I learnt something new from you, but I need some time to check how this would merge with my program, now I am using Tim's method, it works excellent.

Comment: I studies this method nearly today, I also tried to use this method as well, it also works perfect with my requirements. You really introduce another great function with me. It seems that application.rum works fine even I put my function in module1. Thank you very much, DarXyde!!

Comment: No worries, glad i could help :)

Answer (score 0):

If your functions are in the userform code module you can do this:

```
Private Sub cmCheck_Click()
    Recheck Me.txtA
    Recheck Me.txtB
End Sub

Private Sub Recheck(target As MSForms.Control)
    If target.Value Like "*ABC*" Then

        'Use CallByName to run the functions...
        target.Value = CallByName(Me, target.Name & "_Min", VbMethod) & " AND " & _
                       CallByName(Me, target.Name & "_Max", VbMethod) & " (check)"

        CallByName Me, target.Name & "_check", VbMethod

    End If
End Sub

'functions being called start here....
Function txtA_Min()
    txtA_Min = 1
End Function

Function txtA_Max()
    txtA_Max = 10
End Function

Function txtB_Min()
    txtB_Min = 11
End Function

Function txtB_Max()
    txtB_Max = 20
End Function
```

Comment: Excellent!! I am a new self-learner in excel vba. You introduced me with a method that I didn't discover in book. It's a very useful function. But I stuck at the beginning, after studied through website, I discovered the functions should be in public. Now I greatly reduce the line in my program, thank you very much !!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for bothering again, the callbyname function is excellent, my program works fine with a structure similar with the following program:

```
Public Function InputCorr(Target As MSForms.Control) As Boolean

    If FrmAddRecord1Shown Then
        Target.Value = CallByName(frmAddRecord1, Target.Name & "_Min", VbMethod)
    ElseIf FrmAddRecord2Shown Then
        Target.Value = CallByName(frmAddRecord2, Target.Name & "_Min", VbMethod)
    End If

End Function
```

But I want to further slim it to be something like this:

```
Public Function InputCorr(Target As MSForms.Control) As Boolean

    Dim UF As UserForm

    If FrmAddRecord1Shown Then
        set UF = frmAddRecord1
    ElseIf FrmAddRecord2Shown Then
        set UF = frmAddRecord2
    EndIf 

    Target.Value = CallByName(UF, Target.Name & "_Min", VbMethod)

End Function
```

FrmAddRecord1Shown and FrmAddRecord2Shown are boolean, indicating which userform (frmAddRecord1 or frmAddRecord2)is active.

I was stuck at the "UF" part. Thank you very much for all yours sincere help.

Comment: What does "stuck" mean?  BTW you should really post this as a new question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31874510/getting-a-controls-parent-form-vba-vb6